# SignalR Doesn't work Properly in JQuery 3.x

Tags: c#, asp.net, signalr

I created a project for the real-time dashboard. Its working fine with jQuery version 1.x, All clients get notified as expected, but it's not working in Jquery version 3.x, only 1 or 2 clients updated, but others are not getting any server notification for the update, I didn't find any error in any browser (client). I am using JQuery 3.x in my Application.

Js Part

```
  <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>        
  <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.4.1.js"></script>
  <script src="/signalr/hubs"></script>
  <script src="~/Scripts/NewFolder1/Test.js"></script>
```

in Test.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(function () {
    // Reference the hub.
    var hubNotif = $.connection.testHub;

    // Start the connection.
    $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
      getCount();
    });

    // Notify while anyChanges.
    hubNotif.client.updatedData = function () {
      getCount();
    };
  });
});

function getCount() {
  var url = "../Home/GetCount";
  $.post(url, function(rData) {
    $("#MyCount").html(rData);

  });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have used signalR with jquery 3.X

Here I give u my code. hope it will help you to solve your problem.

in my aspx page:

```
<script src="<%=ResolveUrl("Scripts/jquery-3.3.1.min.js") %>"></script>
<script src="<%=ResolveUrl("Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.4.0.js") %>"></script>

<!--Reference the autogenerated SignalR hub script. -->
<script src="/signalr/hubs"></script>



<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {

        var chat = $.connection.chatHub;

        // Get the user name.
        $('#displayname').val('Chairman');
        chat.client.differentName = function (name) {
            // Prompts for different user name
           // $('#displayname').val(prompt('Please enter different username:', ''));
            chat.server.notify($('#displayname').val(), $.connection.hub.id);
        };

        chat.client.online = function (name) {
            // Update list of users
            if (name == $('#displayname').val())
                $('#onlineList').append('<div class="border" style="color:red;"><img height="8px"src="assets/img/online.png" />  <strong>' + name + ' starts the meeting</strong></div>');
            else {
                $('#onlineList').append('<div class="border">' + name + '</div>');
                $("#users").append('<img height="8px"src="assets/img/online.png" />  <option value="' + name + '">' + name + '</option>');
            }
        };

        chat.client.enters = function (name) {
            $('#chats').append('<div class="border"><i>' + name + ' Joined the Meeting</i></div>');
            $("#users").append('<option value="' + name + '">' + name + '</option>');
            $('#onlineList').append('<div class="border">' + name + '</div>');
        };
        // Create a function that the hub can call to broadcast chat messages.
        chat.client.broadcastMessage = function (name, message) {
            //Interpret smileys
            message = message.replace(":)", "<img src=\"/emoticons/smile.png\" class=\"smileys\" />");
            message = message.replace(";)", "<img src=\"/emoticons/wink.png\" class=\"smileys\" />");
            message = message.replace(":D", "<img src=\"/emoticons/laugh.png\" class=\"smileys\" />");

            //display the message
            $('#chats').append('<div class="border" style="border-top:groove"><span style="color:blue">' + name + '</span>: ' + message + '</div>');
        };

        chat.client.disconnected = function (name) {
            //Calls when someone leaves the page
            $('#chats').append('<div class="border"><i>' + name + ' leaves the Meeting</i></div>');
            $('#onlineList div').remove(":contains('" + name + "')");
            $("#users option").remove(":contains('" + name + "')");
        }

        // Start the connection.
        $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
            //Calls the notify method of the server
            chat.server.notify($('#displayname').val(), $.connection.hub.id);

            $('#sendmessage').click(function () {
                if ($("#users").val() == "All") {
                    // Call the Send method on the hub. 
                    chat.server.send($('#displayname').val(), $('#message').val());
                }
                else {
                    chat.server.sendToSpecific($('#displayname').val(), $('#message').val(), $("#users").val());
                }
                // Clear text box and reset focus for next comment. 
                $('#message').val('').focus();
            });

        });
    });
</script>
<div style="margin-top: 10px">
    <input type="hidden" id="displayname" />
    <div style="height: 80%;">
        <div id="chats" style="width: 80%; float: left;"></div>
        <div id="onlineList" style="width: 19%; float: right; border-left: solid red 2px; height: 100%;">
            <div style="font-size: 20px;background-color: cadetblue; border:double; color:white">Online Users</div>
        </div>
    </div>

        <div style="float: left; height: 90%; top: 10%; position: relative;">
            <textarea spellcheck="true" id="message" style="width: 625px; height: 80%"></textarea>
        </div>
        <div style="position: relative; top: 30%; float: left;">
            <input type="button" id="sendmessage" value="Send" />
        </div>
        <div style="position: relative; top: 30%; float: left;">
            <select id="users">
                <option value="All">All</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
```

chatHub class... my code is:

```
public class ChatHub : Hub
{
        static ConcurrentDictionary<string, string> dic = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, string>();



    public void Send(string name, string message)
    {
        // Call the broadcastMessage method to update clients.
        Clients.All.broadcastMessage(name, message);
    }

    public void sendToSpecific(string name, string message, string to)
    {
        // Call the broadcastMessage method to update clients.
        Clients.Caller.broadcastMessage(name, message);
        Clients.Client(dic[to]).broadcastMessage(name, message);
    }

    public void Notify(string name, string id)
    {
        if (dic.ContainsKey(name))
        {
            Clients.Caller.differentName();
        }
        else
        {
            dic.TryAdd(name, id);

            foreach (KeyValuePair<String, String> entry in dic)
            {
                Clients.Caller.online(entry.Key);
            }

            Clients.Others.enters(name);
        }
    }

    public override Task OnDisconnected(bool stopCalled)
    {
        var name = dic.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Value == Context.ConnectionId.ToString());
        string s;
        dic.TryRemove(name.Key, out s);
        return Clients.All.disconnected(name.Key);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @abdullahAlMamun vai, I already solved this, that was actually visual studio catch's problem, when signalR run with old js in the first time, After updating js It's not working as expected, then I clean up my project, update Latest Js, and then problem solved automatically. This problem took three days of my life Brother.

Comment: @Sraban75 Could you explain more about how you solved this?